# ngIf causes error: Conditional Expression requires all 3 expressions at the end of expression

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, angular-validation

I am attempting to write form control specific validation error messages in a form group. I have found several tutorials and examples online ([such as this one](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation))  outlining a seemingly simple *ngIf div that shows an error message if errors are detected on the control.

The problem is that when I attempt to do this I recieve this strange error

`NG5002: Parser Error: Conditional expression port?.errors?['required'] requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression`

I have several other *ngIf conditions on this page that work just fine. Here is my relevant
code

```html
                <form-field labelText="Port" [hasError]="port?.invalid && (port?.dirty || key?.touched)" [isRequired]="true">
                    <input id="port" formControlName="port" type="password">
                    <ul *ngIf="port?.invalid && (port?.touched || key?.dirty)">
                        <li *ngIf="port?.errors?['required']">Port is Required</li>
                        <li *ngIf="port?.errors?['pattern']">Invalid Port Number</li>
                    </ul>
                </form-field>
```

```js
    ngOnInit() {
        this.store.dispatch(SettingsActions.enterMaintenance());
        this.detailsForm = new FormGroup({
            id: new FormControl(''),
            name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            productName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            number: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            isSamlAuthRequired: new FormControl(Boolean),
            iAdapterSetting: new FormGroup({
                server: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
                port: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.regexValidPort)]),
                key: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
                headerVersion: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
                iAdapterInstitutionId: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
                isSSL: new FormControl(Boolean),
                tlsSecurityStrength: new FormControl(''),
            }),
        });
        this.setValue();
    }
    get port() {
        return this.detailsForm.get('iAdapterSetting.port');
    }
```

I tried to add an inline conditional alternative like this.

```html
                <form-field labelText="Port" [hasError]="port?.invalid && (port?.dirty || port?.touched)">
                    <input id="Port" formControlName="port" type="text">
                    <ul *ngIf="port?.invalid && (port?.touched || port?.dirty)" class="rui-form-validation-errors">
                        <li *ngIf="port?.errors?['required']: false">Port is Required</li>
                        <li *ngIf="port?.errors?['pattern'] : false">Invalid Port Number</li>
                    </ul>
                </form-field>
```

This actually resolves the build error, But this seems incorrect and it should be unnecessary according to every example on the internet I can find. On top of that, they are still both evaluated to true together. The key doesn't seem to make a difference. If on of the conditions triggers then both messages show up and that is not the behavior I need.

[image]

Comment: Hi Riley, do you want to display only one message at a time. You don't want both messages displayed at once, am I correct?

Comment: Looks like the compiler is treating `port?.errors?['required']` as ternary operator because of the `?`

Comment: @GouthamHarshith I only want to display the message relevant to the problem. So if the field is empty it should show the `field is required` message, and if the port number is out of range it should show `invalid port number`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expression `port?.errors?['required']` is not valid syntax in Typescript because
property check operator is `.?` not just `?`. You can't access optional property that way. Valid syntax is `port?.errors?.['required']`.

Comment: Thank you, I want to note that `port?.errors?.required` does NOT work. it results in this error
```error TS4111: Property 'required' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['required'].  52                         <li *ngIf="port?.errors?.required">Port is Required</li>```

However putting the syntax with the brackets and the dot resulted in successful compilation and the behavior I was seeking. If you edit your answer to remove the first option I will accept it

Comment: Removed possible solution `port?.errors?.required` because it's not suitable in this particular case, although syntactically is absolutely correct. If you fully type `port` variable or disable `noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature` compiler option it will work too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form-field labelText="Port" [hasError]="port?.invalid && (port?.dirty || port?.touched)">
                    <input id="Port" formControlName="port" type="text">
                    <ul *ngIf="port?.invalid && (port?.touched || port?.dirty)" class="rui-form-validation-errors">
                        <li *ngIf="port?.errors?.required">Port is Required</li>
                        <li *ngIf="port?.errors?.pattern">Invalid Port Number</li>
                    </ul>
                </form-field>
```

Comment: I have tried this

```error TS4111: Property 'required' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['required'].

52                         <li *ngIf="port?.errors?.required">Port is Required</li>```

Comment: and of course simply removing the `?` results in a value possibly null error